# How do I update a quantity in db

Tags: java, mysql

Im trying to update the quantity column in my DB called product. I want to update the drink fanta from a quantity of 30 to 29. Once i get it working i can do the same for all other products then. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You
Here is my DB

'7', 'Fanta', 'Fanta Orange', '2', 'Cold Drinks', 'Coca Cola', '30' <== quantity column

Here is my code so far.

```
// Update Stock
    public void update() 
    {
        Connection conn = null;

        try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/team_project_schema?useSSL=false", "root" , "password");

            String query = "UPDATE product SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ProductName = 'Fanta' and Quantity > 0";
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(7, "Fanta");
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            // If we don't have a error, close the connection!
            System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

        } finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                if (conn != null) 
                {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) 
            {

            }
        }

    }

package testers;

import classes.Stock;
import java.util.*;

public class StockTester 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // create object of Stock
        Stock stock = new Stock();


        // print out stock from DB
        System.out.println("Reading All Products From DB... ");
        System.out.println();
        ArrayList <Stock> allStock = stock.getProducts();
        Iterator<Stock> Iterator = allStock.iterator();

        while (Iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Stock displayStock = Iterator.next();
            System.out.println(displayStock.getProductID() + " \t" + displayStock.getProductName()
            + " \t" + displayStock.getProductDesc() + " \t" + displayStock.getSection()
            + " \t" + displayStock.getSupplierName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please narrow your question down to a specific problem that would be on-topic for this site.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and [How to ask a good question when I'm not sure what I'm looking for?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262527/how-to-ask-a-good-question-when-im-not-sure-what-im-looking-for)

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way for me its easiest :

```
conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPDATE `product` SET `quantity`='29' WHERE ProductName = 'Fanta' and Quantity > 0';")
```

you just have to write the new  quantity not how much you want to take .
ex:29 not -1;

Answer (score 0):

You can send the `productId` to your `update` method and send it as parameter in your `Prepared Satement`.

```
public void update() 
{
   ...
   String query = "UPDATE product SET Quantity = Quantity - 1 WHERE ProductID = ? and Quantity > 0";
   PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   pstmt.setString(1, this.productID);
   pstmt.executeUpdate();
   ...
}
```

In your test class you can update like this.

```
while (Iterator.hasNext())
{
  Stock displayStock = Iterator.next();
  displayStock.update();
}
```

Comment: How would i run the update in my tester then?. the name of my class are Stock and StockTester

Comment: tester posted below the main Stock class

Comment: Yes it resides in the Stock class

Comment: Ok thank you. It is working. So how would i go about making it only deduct the stock that is sold. Lets say i have a till and i add n number of items to the orderlist such as 1 x Fanta, 1 x BLT, 2 x Danish Pastry. How would i only deduct what i sold at that moment because right now its taking quantity away from every item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any parameters in your SQL, so the code below should fail:

```
pstmt.setString(7, "Fanta");
```

Your SQL should probably look something like:

```
String query = "UPDATE product SET Quantity = Quantity - ? WHERE ProductName = ?";
pstmt.setInt(1, 1); // the first parameter is the index of the variable in your SQL
pstmt.setString(2, "Fanta");
```

UPDATE:
Lets suppose you have an "Order" item and it contains a "List" of "LineItems"

```
public void updateStockCounts(Order order) {
    Connection conn = getConnection(); // get a connection to the database
    conn.setAutoCommit(false); // dont update the db automatically, let me do it
    String sql = "UPDATE product SET Quantity = Quantity - ? WHERE ProductName = ?";
    PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    for(LineItem lineItem : order.getLineItems()) {
        pStmt.setInt(1, lineItem.getQuantity()); // this is the quantity sold
        pStmt.setString(2, lineItem.getStockName()); // this the name of the product 'Fanta' for example
        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    } // go on to the next lineItem if there are any more
    conn.commit(); // update all processed items now.
}
```

There are of course other things to do in here like error checking, example the connection to the database could get interrupted.

Comment: How can i only update what was sold in terms of quantity, lets say i have a till and i add a product to the order. when i hit pay, it should only deduct the quantity of what was sold instead of deducting each quantity.

Comment: I updated the code to give you an example. You'll have to figure out how to handle exceptions.

Comment: I do not have a class called LineItem or a method called getLineItems()

Comment: Use what you have then. If I were architecting a system like this, I would have an Order class that contains all of the line items on that order and maybe total money and tax, and I would have a LineItem class that has fields for quantity and stock name. You could have these fields on the order itself, in an Object Oriented language like Java though, I would have a different class like I've shown.

Comment: How would I Call my methods now in the GUI class to update my DB after a sale is made? Would I just call it like: for a small coffee for example would i just call jbtSmall.update(); ?

Comment: jbtSmall is a JButton for a small coffee